# AWS DynamoDB data with and/or without types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the `aws-sdk` for NodeJS to interact with a DynamoDB table. This is my first look at DynamoDB.

When using a call like `getItem()` or `updateItem()`, the data structure includes types, like this:

```
{
  'a': { S: 'My string' }
}
```

Is there any way to pass and receive these objects without the types..? So...

```
{
  'a': 'My string'
}
```

Or, any helper functions already written that will convert objects to and from this format..?

```
const data = dbToObj({ 'a': { S: 'My string' } })
// { 'a': 'My string' }
```

So I could convert to it when populating call params, and convert from it when receiving data.

Trying to avoid accessing my data like:

```
const myData = data.Item.something.M.somethinElse.M.qwerty.S
```

I know I could write something myself, just wondering if anyone knows of functions/options already available that would do this. I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found this:

- https://github.com/kayomarz/dynamodb-data-types
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types

Exactly what I was looking for.

Install: `npm i dynamodb-data-types`

Provides `wrap({ 'a': 'My string' })` and `unwrap({ 'a': { S: 'My string' } })` methods for doing the conversion to and from plain objects.

**UPDATE**

I've now also found this: [`AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html), which is part of the `aws-sdk`.

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB by abstracting away the notion of attribute values. This abstraction annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types.

**UPDATE 2**

This is being worked on by Amazon under their `awslabs` github page:

[Amazon DynamoDB Automarshaller](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/tree/master/packages/dynamodb-auto-marshaller)

> This library provides a Marshaller class that converts native JavaScript values to DynamoDB AttributeValues and back again. It's designed to work with ES6 features like sets, maps, and iterables, and can be configured to support data types only supported by JavaScript (such as empty binary buffers) or by Amazon DynamoDB (such as numbers of arbitrary size) with minimal tradeoffs.

It's part of their [DynamoDB DataMapper For JavaScript](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) package.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18172829)

Comment: I agree in general and I've updated my answer a bit. However, in this specific case all I'm doing is repeating method calls provided by `dynamodb-data-types`, and as such they are subject to change just as much as the link is. I don't have any code to share which isn't `dynamodb-data-types` code, since the answer to my question is directly to use this library. Make sense..? I seem to have been down-voted already though! :-(

Answer (score 1):

We use [dynamo-easy](https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy) with typescript for our production applications. (directly from browser or inside Lambda functions)

It provides the mapping from JS to DynamoDB types but also some nice abstraction for the request API.

```
import { Model, PartitionKey, DynamoStore } from '@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy'

@Model()
export class Person {
  @PartitionKey()
  id: string
  name: string
  yearOfBirth: number
}

const personStore = new DynamoStore(Person)

personStore
  .scan()
  .whereAttribute('yearOfBirth').equals(1958)
  .exec()
  .then(res => console.log('ALL items with yearOfBirth == 1958', res))
```

*full disclosure: I am one of the authors of the library*

Answer (score 0):

Dynogels offer a cleaner way to handle without worrying about types.
We use it in production and works without any issues.

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

```
Account.create({email: 'foo@example.com', name: 'Foo Bar', age: 21}, function (err, acc) {
  console.log('created account in DynamoDB', acc.get('email'));
});
```

It is a ODM (Object Data Mapper) for dynamodb.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com/api) is another modelling tool that can abstract even more extraneous code away. The github is [here](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose). I think its built on top of the AWS documentclient, although I haven't done much digging.