# AWS DynamoDB execute_statement Without Data Types in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using boto3 to query my DynamoDB table using PartiQL,

```
dynamodb = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id='<aws_access_key_id>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws_secret_access_key>',
    region_name='<region_name>'
)

resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(Statement='SELECT * FROM TryDaxTable')
```

Now, the response you get contains a list of dictionaries that looks something like this,

```
{'some_data': {'S': 'XXX'},
  'sort_key': {'N': '1'},
  'partition_key': {'N': '7'}
}
```

Along with the attribute name (e.g. `partition_key`), you get the data type of the value (e.g. `'N'`) and then the actual value (e.g. `'7'`). It can also be seen that value does not actually come in specified data type either (e.g. `partition_key` is supposed to be a number (`N`), but the value is a string.

Is there some way I can get my results in a list of dictionaries without the types and also with the types applied?

That would mean something like this,

```
{'some_data': 'XXX',
  'sort_key': 1,
  'partition_key': 7
}
```

Notice that in addition to removing the data types, the values have also been converted to the correct type.

This is a simple record, but more complex ones can have lists and nested dictionaries. More information is available here,
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.execute_statement

Is there some way that I can get the data in the format I desire?

Or has somebody already written a function to parse the data?

I know there are several questions regarding this posted already, but most of them relate to SDKs in other languages. For instance,

[AWS DynamoDB data with and/or without types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675920/aws-dynamodb-data-with-and-or-without-types)

I did not find one that has addressed this issue in Python.

Note: I want to continue to use PartiQL to query my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `.resource` instead of `.client` you'll live at a higher abstraction layer.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('name')
```

You want to use PartiQL which returns the lower-level data format, so you'll probably have to follow the advice at [How to convert a boto3 Dynamo DB item to a regular dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755888/how-to-convert-a-boto3-dynamo-db-item-to-a-regular-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: It does not look like I can use PartiQL with this, huh? I want to continue to use PartiQL.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, added more to the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I had no idea this existed. Thank you.